# Why Datatables is very slow with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I have a project with laravel in which he used "yajra / laravel-datatables" the problem is that it is very slow when it comes to fetching server data.

**This project has a total of 11,000 records and I paginate it with Datatables of 10 in 10. To bring the first 10 it takes more than 3 seconds.**

[image: error]

*We have another project that was done natively with PHP and Datatables and there are about 50,000 records and it works instantaneously by bringing the first 10 records plus it is the same computing capacity (It takes 100 milliseconds).*

My infrastructure is in Amazon Web Services.

Because of the way we deliver the data to Datatables, I suspect that it is bringing all the data from the database and delivers 10 records to the interface only. However, it takes longer since it gets all the records in the database.

```php
$query = DB :: select( 'QUERY SQL' );
return DataTables :: of( $query ) -> toJson();
```

*Running the query in workbench takes about 200 milliseconds to bring all the information.*

Comment: It is kinda hard to debug with you without seeing the actual code. However you could try adding in a listener for queries to see which queries are running. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#listening-for-query-events

Comment: Yes, you are building a DataTable from a collection of 11k rows. Don't query data before the table, let the package do the querying.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your comment and is effectively bringing all the records of the database. The issue is that I need to use the raw query for some implementation issues.

Comment: Someone knows how to make with a query raw and only extract the data they need in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure how to create an entire `Builder` instance from a raw query, but what you definitely can do is using a subquery:

```
$builder = DB::query()->fromSub(
    DB::raw($theQueryString),
    'wrapped_query'
);

return datatable($builder)->toJson();
```

This has also the advantage that both sorting and searching will work flawlessly even with joined tables.